# Hashing image names

Tags: php, hash, sha

I'm uploading images to S3 and I wish to create a unique name for each one uploaded.

I'm using intervention to make the image:

```
$img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
```

Then I hash the image:

```
$name = hash('sha256', $img);
```

The problem is, when I upload the same image, it's given the same name.

How can I get around this?

Comment: try `$name = hash('sha256', $imgm, false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to add a salt to it.  Even appending the date/time should give you an unique name.
Cheers!

PS (edit):

```
$data = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->encode('data-url'); 

$name = hash('sha256', $data . strval(time()));
```

First we encode the data in a "string way" so we can concatenate the time value as a string.

If you want extra "randomness" add a user cookie, username etc.

Final solution:

$data = implode('', file($file->getRealPath()));

$name = hash('sha256', $data . strval(time()));

Comment: $data = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->encode('data-url');
$name = hash('sha256', $img . strval(time()));

Comment: My latest edit is not optimal, but should work. Haven't tested it!

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to encode the image as data-url, Using your method would mean I would have to encode it twice. one for saving it and the other for the hash name.

Comment: that is why i said it is not optimal. 
You could just read it :

$data = implode('', file($file->getRealPath()));

Comment: also ... why not use md5. It is faster that sha. Are you going to process millions of photos? ( worring about collisions ?!) if not, md5 is good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [com_create_guid()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) to create a global unique identifier instead? This would give you a unique name for each file. For example:

```
$name = com_create_guid();
```

Comment: That's an extension? I'd rather not use an extension.

Comment: Oh yes. There's also uniqid() http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.uniqid.php which is a basic extension too. It's common (at least in the .NET world) to use UUID's to generate unique filenames for uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to avoid this is by using a timestamp for each upload.
Just combine the $img with current timestamp by using the `time()` function.

For example:

```
hash('sha256', $img+time());
```

Comment: Image could not be converted to int

Answer (score -1):

You could try add a rand()

```
hash('sha256', $img . rand(1,100) );
```

Comment: This still gives him the danager that the same random number will be chosen. 

Even if its a 1%, you still didn't eliminate the problem he is trying to solve.